# android - switch two values with '&'

Tags: android, switch-statement

```
   switch (attribute.inputType & EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_CLASS) {
            case EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER:
            case EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME:
            case EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE:
                mCurKeyboard = mSymbolsKeyboard;
                break;

            case EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT: 
                mCurKeyboard = mQwertyKeyboard;
        }
```

what does it means?

my Testing result is:

```
attribute.inputType = 17
EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_CLASS = 15
```

it switch to `case EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` which is `= 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In binary...

```
10001 // 17
01111 // 15
```

...the `&` operator indicates that you want to match the `bits` where both are `1`.

Bit-wise it looks like this...

```
10001 // 17
01111 // 15
-----
00001 // 17 & 15
```

Only the last `bit` of both numbers match as being `1`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bitwise operator (bitwise AND) and can shortly be described like this:

```
0110 & 1101 = 0100
```

For more information check [this](http://vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html) tutorial out.

Comment: Not a bad tutorial. Good share.